# Layer from SQL Server fails when it contains WKT or area calculated from geometry

Tags: qgis, geometry, sql-server-spatial

QGIS 3.28, MS SQL Server 2016, EPSG:25832

I'm trying to open a view from a MSSQL database. It works ok, until I include columns that contain the WKT expression of the geometry, or the area of polygons.

The WKT string is made using `SP_GEOMETRY.STAsText()` and the area is calculated like this: `round(SP_GEOMETRY.STArea()/10000,1) as areal_HA`

Without these columns, QGIS loads the view without problems, 320 lines with all values correctly. But when I include the to columns by altering the view in MS SQL Management Studio, I only get one single row in the table in QGIS, though I can see all the polygons in the map.
If I use the "Identify features" tool to look into the features in the map, then QGIS freezes.

In Management Studio, the view performs flawlessly...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain more information: The coordinate reference used in your table and whether you have validated your geometries.

Comment: sorry forgot the coordinate system. geometries works great when i load the view without the two attributes..

Comment: testet geometries in database with STIsValid(), all geometries is ok ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like casting the columns to nvarchar and decimal solved the problem.